# Loop to read all rows in igHierarchicalGrid grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui

I need for loop to read all the rows with there child to check the status of check box , in this `igHierarchicalGrid` i have 4 level , i cant find the best way to read all rows and child one by one

I have tried getInfo(), but this function only get me the Main level of `igHierarchicalGrid`

```
function getInfo() {   
  var $grid = $("#grid");
  var RowSelected = $("#grid").igHierarchicalGrid("option", "dataSource");

  for (var i = 0; i < RowSelected.length; i++) {
    var cell = $grid.igGrid("cellAt", 1, i)
    var $checkBox = $(cell.children[0]);
    if ($checkBox.prop("checked")) {
        updatetrue(RowSelected[i].FCU_SCREEN_NAME, RowSelected[0].FCU_TYPE, RowSelected[i].FCU_PARENT_NODE, RowSelected[i].FCU_CHAILD_NODE);

    } else {
        updatefalse(RowSelected[i].FCU_SCREEN_NAME, RowSelected[0].FCU_TYPE, RowSelected[i].FCU_PARENT_NODE, RowSelected[i].FCU_CHAILD_NODE);

    }
  }
  alert("Updated Successfuly");
}
```

this is the grid :

```
$("#grid").igHierarchicalGrid({
    width: "100%",

    maxDataBindDepth: 4,

    //initialExpandDepth: 4,
    dataSource: Main, //Array of objects defined above
    fixedHeaders: true,
    primaryKey: "FCU_SNO",
    autoGenerateColumns: true,
    rowExpanding: function (e, args) {

        var grid = args.owner, expandedRows, i;
        expandedRows = $(args.parentrow).closest('tbody').find('tr[state=e]');
        for (i = 0; i < expandedRows.length; i++) {
            grid.collapse(expandedRows[i]);
        }

    },
    width: '99%',
    height: '480px',
    columns: [
        { headerText: "<br/>Code", key: "FCU_SNO", dataType: "int", width: "5%", hidden: true },
        { headerText: "Status", key: "FCU_SCREEN_FLAG", dataType: "bool", width: "5%", template: mytemplate },
        { headerText: "Screen", key: "FCU_SCREEN_NAME", dataType: "string", width: "40%" },
        { headerText: "FCU_TYPE", key: "FCU_TYPE", dataType: "string",  hidden: true },
        { headerText: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", key: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true},
        { headerText: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", key: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true},
    ],
    autofitLastColumn: false,
    autoGenerateColumns: false,
    dataSource: Main,
    responseDataKey: "results",
    autoCommit: true,
    primaryKey: "FCU_SNO",
    dataRendered: function (evt, ui) {
        ui.owner.element.find("tr td:nth-child(4)").css("text-align", "left");
    },

    features: featuresList,
    //defaultChildrenDataProperty: "Details1",
    columnLayouts: [{
        name: "Level1",
        features: featuresList,
        childrenDataProperty: "Details1",
        autoGenerateLayouts: true,
        autoGenerateColumns: false,
        fixedHeaders: true,
        primaryKey: "FCU_PARENT_NODE",
        columns: [
            { headerText: "<br/>Code", key: "FCU_SNO", dataType: "int", width: "5%", hidden: true },
            { headerText: "Status", key: "FCU_SCREEN_FLAG", dataType: "bool", width: "5%", template: mytemplate },
            { headerText: "Screen", key: "FCU_SCREEN_NAME", dataType: "string", width: "40%" },
            { headerText: "FCU_TYPE", key: "FCU_TYPE", dataType: "string", hidden: true },
            { headerText: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", key: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
            { headerText: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", key: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
        ],
        columnLayouts: [
            {
                name: "Level2",
                features: featuresList,
                childrenDataProperty: "Details2",
                autoGenerateLayouts: true,
                autoGenerateColumns: false,
                primaryKey: "FCU_PARENT_NODE",
                columns: [
                    { headerText: "<br/>Code", key: "FCU_SNO", dataType: "int", width: "5%", hidden: true },
                    { headerText: "Status", key: "FCU_SCREEN_FLAG", dataType: "bool", width: "5%", template: mytemplate },
                    { headerText: "Screen", key: "FCU_SCREEN_NAME", dataType: "string", width: "40%" },
                    { headerText: "FCU_TYPE", key: "FCU_TYPE", dataType: "string", hidden: true },
                    { headerText: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", key: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
                    { headerText: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", key: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
                ],
                columnLayouts: [
                    {
                        name: "Level3",
                        features: featuresList,
                        childrenDataProperty: "Details3",
                        autoGenerateLayouts: true,
                        autoGenerateColumns: false,
                        primaryKey: "FCU_PARENT_NODE",
                        columns: [
                            { headerText: "<br/>Code", key: "FCU_SNO", dataType: "int", width: "5%", hidden: true },
                            { headerText: "Status", key: "FCU_SCREEN_FLAG", dataType: "bool", width: "5%", template: mytemplate },
                            { headerText: "Screen", key: "FCU_SCREEN_NAME", dataType: "string", width: "40%" },
                            { headerText: "FCU_TYPE", key: "FCU_TYPE", dataType: "string", hidden: true },
                            { headerText: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", key: "FCU_PARENT_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
                            { headerText: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", key: "FCU_CHAILD_NODE", dataType: "number", hidden: true },
                        ],

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The igHierarchicalGrid API offers a method called [allChildrenWidgets](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ui.ighierarchicalgrid#methods:allChildrenWidgets), which would give you an array of all the child widgets that have been created. 
Note that the parent grid creates such instances dynamically when the user expands a given row, not for all the currently visible rows in the parent grid.

That means if you have expanded only a single row, calling allChildrenWidgets would return an array with a single widget instance. 
Once you get this array, it would be possible to iterate over it and get the dataSource of every child grid. This dataSource object is a transformed copy of the original data that has been used when initializing the child grid, and once the user checks a checkbox, this dataSource would be updated. You may assign it to a variable, like this:

```
let currentChild = $("#hierarchicalGrid").igHierarchicalGrid('allChildrenWidgets')[0]
```

Note the ‘[0]’ at the end – that is because the allChildrenWidgets returns an array. If you use it in a for loop, you would replace it with some dynamic index.

Now that we have a reference to the current child grid, we could call its dataSource’s [dataView](https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.2/ig.datasource#methods:dataView) method – that would give us the current data that is rendered in this child grid, and would allow us to check the records in order to see which ones have been checked:

```
let currentDataView = child.dataSource.dataView();
// ….
// some custom logic for checking the records….
```

Please note that allChildrenWidgets returns a ***flattened*** array of all child widgets, containing all the hierarchy levels – you would **not** have to call it on the current child widget recursively in order to get to its level 3 children grids.